# Connecting GET request and POST request in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, nodejs-server

I'm still a beginner in NodeJS with little resource for reference.
How can I connect this two script together ?

`getproductinfo.js` perform a GET request to an API endpoints and gets all data needed by `Saveproductinfo.js` to do a POST request and save all info into database API.

getProductinfo.js

```
var axios = require('axios');

var config = {
  method: 'get',
  url: 'http://localhost:3001/api/get-products?keywords=shirt&min_sale_price=1&max_sale_price=100&page_no=1',
  headers: { }
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

saveProductinfo.js

```
    var axios = require('axios');
var qs = require('qs');
var data = qs.stringify({
  'product_id': '1',
  'product_title': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'promotion_link': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'sale_price': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'first_level_category_id': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'second_level_category_id': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'second_level_category_name': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'first_level_category_name': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'original_price_currency': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'lastest_volume': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'shop_url': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'product_detail_url': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'original_price': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'product_main_image_url': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'product_small_image_urls': 'vxzvxzvxz' 
});
var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/product',
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var axios = require('axios');

var qs = require('qs');
var data = qs.stringify({
  'product_id': '1',
  'product_title': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'promotion_link': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'sale_price': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'first_level_category_id': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'second_level_category_id': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'second_level_category_name': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'first_level_category_name': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'original_price_currency': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'lastest_volume': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'shop_url': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'product_detail_url': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'original_price': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'product_main_image_url': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'product_small_image_urls': 'vxzvxzvxz' 
});

var productDetails = {};
async function getProductInfo() {
  var config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://localhost:3001/api/get-products?keywords=shirt&min_sale_price=1&max_sale_price=100&page_no=1',
    headers: { }
  };
  try {
    const result = axios(config);
    productDetails = result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

async function Saveproductinfo() {
  // before creating config data you can 
  // create data using productDetails and then save it
 // taking values based on schema you shared in the comment
  data = qs.stringify({
  'product_id': '1',
  'product_title': productDetails[0].product_title,
  'promotion_link': 'productDetails[0].promotion_link',
  'sale_price': 'productDetails[0].sale_price',
  'first_level_category_id': 'productDetails[0].first_level_category_id', // do similary for all properties
  'second_level_category_id': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'second_level_category_name': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'first_level_category_name': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'original_price_currency': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'lastest_volume': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'shop_url': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'product_detail_url': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'original_price': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'product_main_image_url': 'vxzvxzvxz',
  'product_small_image_urls': 'vxzvxzvxz' 
});
  var config = {
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/product',
    headers: { 
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    data : data
  };
  
  try {
    const results = await axios(config)
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(`Error is ${e}`);
  }
}

module.exports = {getProductInfo, Saveproductinfo}
```

Now, you have two methods that can be unit tested well. You can import them and run them sequentially using async/await.

```
const {getProductInfo, Saveproductinfo } = require('filepath');

await getProductInfo(); // await here will work if node v14 >
await Saveproductinfo();
```

Comment: what do I replace 'vxzvxzvxz' with ?

Comment: Check now you want to pass the productinfo to data. I have updated that there can be other ways to do the same. You have to update the data field from the data received in productInfo.

Comment: 1 example please ?

Comment: Can you add productInfor schema in question? What do you need in data variable? When you receive productinfo, how many products are there? what do I replace 'vxzvxzvxz' with? You need to replace `vxzvxzvxz` with the data coming from product info and I can't tell how to add that unless I see how data is coming.

Comment: [{"app_sale_price":"0.01","app_sale_price_currency":"USD","commission_rate":"9.0%","discount":"0%","first_level_category_id":200000345,"first_level_category_name":"Women's Clothing","hot_product_commission_rate":"0.0%","lastest_volume":0,"original_price":"0.01","original_price_currency":"USD","product_detail_url":"https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003250477622.html","product_id":1005003250477622,"product_main_image_url":"https://ae04.alicdn.com/kf/H250661b40b3949fba34a48e99df7d6761.jpg",...

Comment: no data added to db

Comment: Did you receive an error? `/api/product` are you able to receive data at this end point of not check your method for sending data or share your end point code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you export your POST function so it can be accessed in your code elsewhere, you should be able to call your `GET` and in the then() callback call your post, like so:

First modify your POST function take in parameters for data:

```
async function postFunction(data){
 axios(config)
 .then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
  })
 .catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
}
```

Then call it with the result of GET function:

```
import <yourPostFunction>
var axios = require('axios');

const config = {
  method: 'get',
  url: 'http://localhost:3001/api/get-products?keywords=shirt&min_sale_price=1&max_sale_price=100&page_no=1',
  headers: { }
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  //GET function has finished running
  const result=JSON.stringify(response.data); //Might need to await this data
const postResult= await postFunction(result);//call your post function

})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```